# ¿Cómo enviar valor por defecto a un input type text con JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

¿Cómo envío un valor por defecto en un `input type="text"`?

Estoy haciendo una aplicación web de una tienda *online*. El caso es que en la caja `input` tipo `text` no me da un valor por defecto, es decir, cuando yo tecleo un cero, me lo deja tal y como está, y lo que necesito es que me dé por defecto un 1.

Ahora bien, en caso de que teclee 0, *JavaScript* me debe dar por defecto el valor 1.

¿Cómo hago esto?

Nota: No estoy usando formularios.

Comment: Puede añadir el atributo `value` con el valor `"1"` dentro del propio elemento HTML.

Comment: Gracias @Javi sí funciona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

un ejemplo con jquery seria

```
   $(function(){                            
        $('#txtNumero').focusout(function(){     
              if($('#txtNumero').val()=="0"){    
                  $('#txtNumero').val("1");                               
              }}                                                            
        )}                                                                    
   )
```

ejemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/madaver1980/pc98k6nc/

recuerda agregar jquery

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplemente agregando un `input` de tipo `number` restringes el valor mínimo y máximo y solo te dejaría ingresar números

```
<input type="number" min="1" max="5" value="1">
```

Espero te sirva, saludos !